# REGEX How can I check if a string has more than 2 spaces in it?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to regex (ECMAscript) check if a string has three or more spaces in it. Essentially, I want the minimum number of spaces to be 3 before it matches. Here are some examples;

"Microsoft and Apple" ***This would NOT match***

"The quick brown fox" **This WOULD match**

"lots of spaces in this sentence" **This WOULD match**

This is the best I have so far;

---

/[\s]{3,}/gm

---

Comment: A string contains at least 3 spaces if it matches the regex / .* .* / (which might be written / (?:.* ){2}/). I'm sure this question has been asked many times so don't be surprised when it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'string' can contain everything (characters and numbers and special chars):

```
/^((.*?)? (.*?)?){3,}?$/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

Put three spaces in the regex, and match anything else around them

`.* .* .* .*`

Answer (score 0):

A regex that makes sure there at least 3 whitespaces in a string is

```
/^(?:\S*\s){3}/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TbMa4R/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\S*\s){3}` - three occurrences of zero or more non-whitespace chars and then a whitespace.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['Microsoft and Apple','The quick brown fox','lots of spaces in this sentence'];
const re = /^(?:\S*\s){3}/;
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', re.test(text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `/[\s]{3,}/gm` matches 3 continuous whitespace characters, and `\s` can also match newlines.

Note that you don't need `/m` as the pattern has no anchors, but you do need `/g` to get all matches.

You can match all spaces   and only get the string that has more than 2 spaces (or if you really want to use `\s` then use that)

```js
[
  "Microsoft and Apple",
  "The quick brown fox",
  "lots of spaces in this sentence"
].forEach(s => {
  if ((s.match(/ /g) || []).length > 2) {
    console.log(s);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This may not be optimally efficient, but you could `split` on spaces and then check the resulting length:

```js
const x = [
 "Microsoft and Apple",
 "The quick brown fox",
 "lots of spaces in this sentence",
]

x.forEach(s => console.log(s, s.split(' ').length > 3))
```